# Placement of footnote on table of contents page

Tags: table-of-contents, pdftex, footnotes, quotchap

I'm using the *quotchap* package and I'm using the `\footnotemark` and `\footnotetext` command in order to provide references to the quotes I'm using in my text. I've placed a quote on my table of contents (which contains multiple pages of TOC content), and would like this footnote to be on the first page of the TOC, rather than on the last page.

Placing the `\footnotetext` command before the `\tableofcontents` command results in the footnote text appearing 2 pages *before* the TOC even begins, so I'm not sure if I'm missing something...

Main file as a minimum working example:

```
\documentclass[11pt, twoside, a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[bookman]{quotchap}
\usepackage[style=authoryear,backref,dashed=false,hyperref=true,autocite=inline,maxcitenames=2,maxbibnames=6,minbibnames=6,uniquelist=false,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{test.bib}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{footnote}{0}
\begin{savequote}[65mm]
But this didn't \emph{feel} like magic. It felt a lot older than that. It felt like music.
\qauthor{Terry \citeauthor{Pratchett1995}, \citetitle{Pratchett1995}\footnotemark}
\end{savequote}

\tableofcontents
\footnotetext[1]{\fullcite[2]{Pratchett1995}}

%\chapter{First}

%\chapter{Second}

%\chapter{Third}

\end{document}
```

.bib file:

```
@book{Pratchett1995,
author = {Pratchett, Terry},
edition = {Paperback},
issn = {9780552140294},
publisher = {Corgi},
title = {{Soul Music}},
year = {1995},
keywords = {Bibliography}
}
```

Result. I would like the footnote to be at the bottom of the first page of the TOC, and not the final page
[image: Result. I would like the footnote to be at the bottom of the first page of the TOC, and not the final page]

Comment: (I don't have a TeX system available so this isn't tested.)  I'm not sure where you want to attach the footnote mark, but as far as the footnote itself, you can force it into the `.toc` file by using `\addtotoc`.  Look up the documentation for this command and also `\addtocline`, and put the appropriate commands and data before the first element (e.g. `\listoffigures` or introduction) that will be listed in the toc.  If that first element is in a separate file that will be `\include`d, add the `\add*toc` command at the top of that file, not before the `\include`; this is a timing necessity.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I was under the impression that the `\addtotoc` command added lines to the actual TOC, which is not what I'm after. I've updated the main post with an image of the results I'm getting at the moment; basically I would like the footnote to appear on the first page of a multi-page TOC instead of on the last page.

Comment: Apologies; my memory was faulty.  `\addtocontents` was the command I intended, and that has now been posted as a workable answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\addtocontents` tag may help you, please refer the below code:

```
\documentclass[11pt, twoside, a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[bookman]{quotchap}
\usepackage[style=authoryear,backref,dashed=false,hyperref=true,autocite=inline,maxcitenames=2,maxbibnames=6,minbibnames=6,uniquelist=false,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{test.bib}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{First}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\footnotetext[1]{\fullcite[2]{Pratchett1995}}}
\section{Test}
\subsection{Test}
\section{Test1}
\subsection{Test}
\section{Test1}
\subsection{Test}
\section{Test}
\subsection{Test}
\section{Test1}
\subsection{Test}
\section{Test1}
\subsection{Test}

\chapter{Second}
\section{Test2}
\subsection{Test}
\section{Test2}
\subsection{Test}
\section{Test}
\subsection{Test}
\section{Test1}
\subsection{Test}
\section{Test1}
\subsection{Test}

\chapter{Third}
\section{Test3}
\subsection{Test}
\section{Test3}
\subsection{Test}
\section{Test}
\subsection{Test}
\section{Test1}
\subsection{Test}
\section{Test1}
\subsection{Test}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is precisely what I needed, thanks a lot!